# calling multiple query parameters in spring rest template

Tags: java, rest, spring-rest

I need to pass the multiple value for a single query parameter in spring rest template , the query parameter is status and it values can be in progress,completed,rejected so I have pass them as values separated by comma , please advise is it the correct approach

```
HttpEntitiy<String> entity = httpEntitiyService.buildHttpEntity(null;"track status");
String url ="https://example/api/2/progress"

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
.querParam("status","inprogress,completed,rejected"); // please advise it is the correct approach
```

Comment: It is entirely up to the server to decide what the `status` value is, so we can't help with that, since we don't know the server.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `queryParams()` method, which is specified as `queryParams` in the interface `UriBuilder` and defined as:

```
public UriComponentsBuilder queryParams(MultiValueMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> params)
```

In your case, you can do:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> myParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
myParams.add("status", "inprogress");
myParams.add("status", "completed");
myParams.add("status", "rejected");
```

And implement it:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
        .queryParams(myParams)
        .build()
        .toUriString();
```

You can also implement in a similar manner, except we just use the `MultiValueMap`:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
        .path("")
        .query("status={status}")
        .buildAndExpand(myParams)
        .toString();
```

Comment: what about if I want to add one more query parameter that if of integer type let say page_size having value of 200 integer type

Comment: @asderfgh It wouldn't matter. `UriComponentsBuilder` automatically encodes the parameters for you, so you could just send it as a string.